# Bit coins disappeared

Tags: wallet

I bought a bit of a bit coin some years ago and forgot about it the the other day had a look and converted a small amount into an ether wallet. I came back the next day and found the bitcoin wallet empty and transferred as per screen shot. Can anyone help. If any more info needed please say. [image: It's the top entry]

[image: Info on transaction]

Comment: maybe someone hacked your account?

Answer (score 2):

You have been robbed, sorry.

Use a strong password/better seed next time.